# Combinatorics...

Tags: combinatorics

"There are 100 homes in a new, linear housing development (all of the houses are in a line), and 80 buyers.  Also, there are two perspective buyers, Alfredo and Bobby, that were childhood friends and must be neighbors.  How many possible arraignments of the neighborhood are there?"

I know the idea, find the total number of combinations (100C80), and then subtract cases that do not meet the conditions.  However, I do not know where to go from here...

I have checked by classbook, and the internet, but have only found questions that involve two people who cannot sit next to one another...

Comment: In those problems where people can *not* sit next to one another, notice that they are generally solved by counting the total number regardless and then subtract the amount where the *must* sit together.  Those problems that you dismissed as not being relevant are in fact *very* relevant and solve your problem.

Comment: The punchline here is that you can pick which of the houses alfredo and bobby will buy, and then pick whether alfredo's house was the one on the left or on the right, putting bobby in the other, and then putting the remaining 78 buyers into other houses.

Comment: As for "*tricky*", not really.  This follows from one of the most basic counting principles... the rule of product... which should have been taught well before you ever heard about binomial coefficients or factorials or anything else.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, there are 80C2 ways for Alfredo and Bobby to choose houses.  Now, how exactly do I account for the fact that they must be adjacent?  Would it be 79C2?

Comment: $\binom{100}{80}$ is the number of ways of selecting a subset of size 80 from a set of size 100.  That would be the number of ways in which 80 houses could be designated as being occupied but not detailing *who* was occupying them, only that they had occupants.  It is heavily implied here that we care about *who* is occupying which house... and that these 80 different prospective buyers are considered distinct.  So, no... $\binom{100}{80}$ is not the number of outcomes here.  $100\frac{80}{~}$ is, where this is shorthand notation for the falling factorial.

Comment: That is, $100\frac{80}{~}=\underbrace{100\cdot 99\cdot 98\cdot 97\cdots 22\cdot 21}_{80~\text{terms}}$.  For accounting for the fact that bobby and alfredo need to be adjacent... like I already alluded to before, let them get in the front of the line and pick their houses first by picking the left-most of the two houses for the pair of them... noting that all of the houses are fine to pick with the exception of the right-most house since there isn't anything further to the right of it.  Choose which of the two alfredo gets.  Distribute remaining people.  $99\cdot 2\cdot 98\frac{78}{~}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Uhhhh... That can't be the only way to solve it...  Doubtless my (7th grade) math class doesn't require knowledge of what you referred to.  Is there not anything simpler?

Comment: "Doesn't require knowledge" of multiplying numbers? If you have three types of pants and five types of shirts, how many different outfits can you make? Your class doesn't require knowledge that you can multiply 3 and 5 to get the answer of 15? I don't believe that. Nothing in the answer I alluded to used anything more complicated than that. The only bigger concept than that I used was shorthand notation for the multiplication of dozens of numbers at once rather than writing each of the 80 numbers being multiplied separately

Comment: My class has been nigh exclusively using choose & permutation notation.  I have a decent handle on both of these.  However, this problem was on a quiz, and not a single student solved it correctly.  Is it in any way possible to solve this problem using the aforementioned methods?

Comment: The rule of product should be taught well before binomial coefficients or permutations.  The formulas for those build upon the understanding of the rule of product.  The notation $100\frac{80}{~}$ is just a different way of writing what your class might be writing as 100P80 and is as already mentioned just the product of the eighty numbers from 100 to 21

Comment: What is the **question???** What are you trying to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you may have been introduced only to permutations and combinations, here is a way you could adopt. Also, since  permutation symbol(s) are not very popular on this site, we shall break it up into *(choose)$\times$(permute)* ie $\dbinom{n}{k}\cdot k!$

- First choose two houses for $A$ and $B$ from the 99 adjacent pairs of houses, and permute them, thus $\;99\cdot2!$ ways.
- Now choose $78$ houses from the $98$ now left, and permute the $78$ persons to reside therein
- Putting the pieces together, $(99\cdot2!)\;\dbinom{98}{78}\cdot 78!$

Comment: I read the original post and I couldn't find a question. What is the question that you are answering?? And how did you find it (the question, not the answer)??

Comment: @bof: From OP'spost, "How many possible arraignments of the neighborhood are there?"

Comment: @bof: I took "arraignments"  as a misprint for arrangements  (since there is no mention of any accusation of crime !)

Comment: If you check the edit history, the line "How many possible arraignments of the neighborhood are there?" was added an hour after I posted my comment and 3 hours after you posted your answer.

Comment: @bof: You are right ! I suppose I went by JMoravitz's comments on the issue, also some of OP's comments re two people not sitting together, and like Sherlock Holmes, solved  the mystery of the missing question before it was found !

Comment: I hope the downvote is not for displaying a sense of humor, supposedly de trop in such a serious business as mathematics !

Comment: I admit that I will sometimes throw a downvote when a user has posted a question which is ambiguous, muddled, or incorrectly stated, and a high reputation user comes along and simply answers it, without either requiring the asker to clean up the question, or even including the needed correction/clarification/interpretation in the answer. Mea maxima culpa.

Comment: @bof: As long as it is not for the humor ! I didn't do it deliberately, on seeing the back and forth between OP and JMoravitz, I was clear what OP wanted, *and a very clear map on how to do it had been provided by JMoravitz,* though using falling factorials, etc not normally taught in class 7. I merely explained it in terms familiar to OP. Anyway, no sweat !